# Нужно решить без курсоров, циклов. Одним запросом

Tags: select, sql

Пусть таблица содержит следующие данные:

```
Product_ID  Operation_Type  Operation_Sum
1           ‘in’             100.00
2           ‘in’             200.00
1           ‘out’            50.00
3           ‘in’             100.00
```

Тогда нарастающий итог будет выглядеть так:

```
Product_ID  Operation_Type  Operation_Sum   Summary
1           ‘in’            100.00          100.00
2           ‘in’            200.00          300.00
1           ‘out’           50.00           250.00
3           ‘in’            100.00          350.00
```

Если бы нужно было считать только по нарастанию, можно написать такой запрос:

```
select Product_ID, Operation_Type, Operation_Sum,
(
    select sum(Operation_Sum) from Table1 as t1 
    where t1.Id <= Table1.Id
)
from Table1
```

Но как быть именно в такой задаче, которую нужно решить без условий, циклов, курсоров и только одним запросом?

Comment: Эмм... я так и не понял вопроса. Вы вроде сами же и правильно написали запрос который вычисляет нарастающим итогом...

Comment: @Barmaley: насколько я понимаю, в коде ТС есть подзапрос, от которого он хотел избавиться.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Operation_Sum, SUM(Operation_Sum) OVER (ORDER BY Id) Running_Sum FROM Table1
```